# Spring boot manual config not scanning Repository objects?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Despite some fairly clear examples, I'm failing to get a manual configuration of a spring boot application to work. I usually allow it to configure right from the application.properties file but the requirement demands that I use multiple data sources. And, yes, I have tried to recreate the Baeldung example (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases) as recommended by the posts I've seen here.  Here is my config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ezcorp.costumerrefresh.db.sqlserver", entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlserverEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "sqlserverTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SqlServerConfig {

    @Bean(name="sqlserverDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource sqlserverDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://aswn-tbd-db01:1433;databaseName=DE_RTDS");
        dataSource.setUsername("cs_user");
        dataSource.setPassword("cs_user");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlserverEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect");
        return builder
            .dataSource(sqlserverDataSource())
            .properties(properties)
            .packages("com.ezcorp.costumerrefresh.domain.sqlserver")
            .persistenceUnit("adminPersistenceUnit")
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager sqlserverTransactionManager(@Qualifier("sqlserverEntityManagerFactory") final EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class CustomerRefreshService {
    @Autowired
    private ExistingLoanModelDataRepository existingLoanModelDataRepository;

    public void execute() {
        System.out.println("show me");
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ExistingLoanModelDataRepository extends CrudRepository<ExistingLoanModelData, Long> {
    ExistingLoanModelData findByCustomerId(Long customerId);
}
```

error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ezcorp.customerrefresh.db.sqlserver.ExistingLoanModelDataRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    ...
```

What am I doing wrong?  This is about as straight-forward as it gets. I've eliminated the other (mongo) config setup to simplify.  This has to be an obvious one...just not to me  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo.

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.ezcorp.cost**u**merrefresh.db.sqlserver", entityManagerFactoryRef = "sqlserverEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "sqlserverTransactionManager")

Comment: Well...that's not smart.  Good catch, dexter125.  Thank you.  It still looks like it's not scanning the packages b/c I can't autowire. I'll post my error below. Thank you for helping me spell  :-)

Comment: Description:
Field existingLoanModelDataRepository in com.ezcorp.customerrefresh.service.CustomerRefreshService required a bean of type 'com.ezcorp.customerrefresh.db.sqlserver.ExistingLoanModelDataRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
 - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ezcorp.customerrefresh.db.sqlserver.ExistingLoanModelDataRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Can you post rest of your configuration? Do you import your `SqlServerConfig` into application config?

Comment: Here is the only other config...I did have config in application.properties as well...do you think there's a config conflict?

## ################# ##
## SQL Server Config ##
## ################# ##
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://aswn-tbd-db01:1433;databaseName=XXXXX
spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXX
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

Comment: Your application.properties looks ok. I found another typo in your code - bean LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean has mispelled package (in builder). I'm not sure if you've corrected it already.

Anyway, I do not see any `@ComponentScan` annotation. I'm not sure how your `CustomerRefreshService` is discovered.